# Whenever I node my code, I get this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

today I wrote this code, it needs to take information from a database of arrays, and store parts of them in a new array. I get this error though. Here is the code:

```
function UpdateGamePrices() {
for(var x = 0;x<gamekeys.keys.length;x++) {
    let appid = gamekeys.keys[x].appid;

    if (fs.existsSync("gamespricelist/"+appid+".json")) {
        let gamedetails = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('gamespricelist/'+appid+'.json'));

        if (gamekeys.keys[x].autoupdateprice == 1) {


            gamekeys.keys[x].price = (((gamedetails[appid].data.price_overview.initial)/10)*1.05);

            jsonstring = JSON.stringify(gamekeys,null,4);
            fs.writeFile("gamekeys.json", jsonstring);
        }
    }
} 
}
UpdateGamePrices();
```

Comment: can you post your JSON?

Comment: i think the json jn your file is not properly formatted.

Comment: I have two JSON files, one of which is over 2 million lines..

Comment: You could check json [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) and see if there are any errors.

Comment: what line threw this error ?   your attempt to stringify or to write in file